# jpandasでcannot import name 'PY3' from 'pandas.compat'のエラーが出る

Tags: python

jpandasをインポートしようとすると以下のエラーが出てしまいます。どのように対応すればよいか全くわからず、どなたか助けていただけますでしょうか？

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-70c197f683a2> in <module>
      2 import pandas as pd
      3 import pandas_datareader.data as pdr
----> 4 import japandas as jpd
      5 key = "10e228baa4bda06e11cbd53567e51fb16043956a"
      6 dlist = jpd.DataReader("00200564", 'estat', appid=key)

G:\Python2\lib\site-packages\japandas\__init__.py in <module>
      2 # coding: utf-8
      3 
----> 4 import japandas.core.strings                                                          # noqa
      5 import japandas.io.data                                                               # noqa
      6 from japandas.io.data import DataReader                                               # noqa

G:\Python2\lib\site-packages\japandas\core\strings.py in <module>
      6 from unicodedata import normalize
      7 
----> 8 from pandas.compat import PY3, iteritems, u_safe
      9 import pandas.core.strings as strings
     10 

ImportError: cannot import name 'PY3' from 'pandas.compat' (G:\Python2\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py)
```

Comment: 念の為、お使いの Python バージョンも質問中に含めておくと回答のヒントになるかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

2019年9月4日の時点で、jpandas は pandas の 0.24.2 より新しい版に対応していないようです。
pandas を 0.24.2 にダウングレードすればうまくいくかもしれません。

情報源は以下です。
https://www.amazon.co.jp/gp/customer-reviews/RN0ZRIEG0JMGQ/

この問題は GitHub の issue にも報告されており、修正を行う [Pull Request も提案](https://github.com/sinhrks/japandas/pull/63) されていますが、反映はされていないようです。

[Cannot import name 'PY3' from 'pandas.compat' · Issue #62 · sinhrks/japandas](https://github.com/sinhrks/japandas/issues/62)